# Can I use third party library like Axios?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

Can I use third party library like Axios in Visualforce lightning components?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean https://github.com/axios/axios? Start by reading [LockerService and Lightning Container Component: Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html).

Comment: Generally speaking, questions that can be answered with a simple "yes" or "no" aren't really a great fit for this site. In cases like these, the fastest way to an answer would be to try for yourself to use this library in a lightning component. If you do try this for yourself and aren't able to make it work, _that_ (I'm getting error x, how do I resolve it?) would be a better question. Of course, if you're only looking for promises, you could look at [Using Javascript Promises](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_promises.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can make an HTTP request directly from the lightning component or by using any library. But sometimes you will may to use the Apex for calling third-party web APIs.

> By default, you can’t make calls to third-party APIs from client-side code. Add a remote site as a CSP Trusted Site to allow client-side component code to load assets from and make API requests to that site’s domain.

Link to the documentation - [enter link description here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_api_calls_platform.htm)